# Zoeppritz equations derivation

Tags: geophysics, seismology

I have been long looking for the derivations and step by step explanation of Zoeppritz matrix but either internet is full of final versions or I can’t find it...I would be very thankful if anyone can direct me or provide me with derivations.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia entry for [**Zoeppritz equations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoeppritz_equations) says:

> A full derivation of these equations can be found in most exploration
>   geophysics text books, such as:
>
> Sheriff, R. E., Geldart, L. P., (1995), 2nd Edition. Exploration
>   Seismology. Cambridge University Press.